# Remote factory reset and changing Google password

Tags: security, android-device-manager

In case I ever lose my Nexus 4 phone, I've opened to the Google Settings app, then tapped "Android Device Manager" and from there, I've enabled both "Remotely locate this device" and "Allow remote factory reset."

Then I can use [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) online from anywhere to ring or reset the phone.

My question is: in the event my phone is stolen/lost, I'd probably change my Google password so the phone can't sync any more while I attempt to find it. If I change my Google password and *then* reset my phone after that, will the remote wipe still work since the Google password changed?

Note: I have 2-factor auth enabled, but keep in mind my phone and the apps in it are already authenticated.

Comment: Why not do a remote wipe, then change your password locally (on your PC)? When you wipe, I assume they can't access your Google accounts anymore.

Comment: In case I merely lost my phone, and I happen to find it un-attended and un-accessed just a few hours later. In those cases, a reset isn't necessary and might destroy any data on the phone that doesn't get synced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not for sake of it, activate 2-step authentication on your Google account?

And just use the random generated password instead, *be sure you have enabled Google to SMS you for any login attempts on your Google account*, and keep your real password hidden. That is what I use here, where-ever I log in, I get an SMS direct to me, asking to enter the verification code, no one else has it.

Also, it would be easier to just revoke it from your Google Account settings page, i.e. access denied.

*I use a spare, crappy phone that I carry with me everywhere, zero chance of anyone trying to steal it, that receives the Google SMS notification, and yes, its a dumbphone :)*

## Edit

**To clarify:** Your account on the device is called a *Application specific password*. See the **Revoke** beside each application specific password.

In event of phone or should I say, *device* getting lost/stolen, its a matter of simply clicking on it. That is what I was referring to, in my case, I have the application called "My smartphone google account signin", and if it gets lost, I click *Revoke*, even after factory reset, data is wiped cleanly for my peace of mind.

I still have my laptop as my *authorized* login, that is, I can use my real password on the laptop, everywhere else Google is accessed, is using the random generated password. And if I was to login on another computer using my real password, the verification code gets sent to my dumbphone which I check and use.

[image: Google Account Application specific settings]

Comment: 2-factor authentication already enabled. Problem: Android device already authorized to access Google account, and 2-factor authentication only protects *new* logins. Could you elaborate on revoking privileges from Google Account settings page? Also, I appreciate the alternative ideas, but I still would like my actual question answered.

Comment: OP: Right, then I think you should re-edit your question to include the fact that 2-step authentication is activated in your case.

Answer (score 1):

> [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) makes it easy to locate, ring, or wipe your device from the web.

So, your question here is:

> in the event my phone is stolen/lost, I'd probably change my Google password (...) will the remote wipe still work since the Google password changed?

What I find somewhat confusing is:

1. Your assumption is that the remote wipe no longer works if the account password has been changed. Why do you assume this? This seems like a huge oversight in the design of ADM, so I don't see why it makes sense to assume this is true without proof. If anything, I think the opposite seems more reasonable to assume given no actual evidence. I encourage you to try it out if you'd like to find out for sure.
2. If we assume for the sake of argument that ADM can no longer wipe a device if the account password has been changed — still, I don't believe this to be true, and if you can prove it, it should definitely be reported as a bug (and if it's not a bug, at least there should be warnings plastered all over the place) — why even take the chance? If you wipe your phone *before* changing the password, this whole concern is a non-issue, right?

Let me know if I am missing something here, but I don't see how anyone can give a meaningful answer to you, except if anyone is willing to try the validity of your claim (which you can also do yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Yup you can't wipe after changing password,

But if are going to do so then do remote wipe and change it.

It requires hardly any time to do this,

After reset your account will no longer be used with device,

If you change password before resetting he can have access to your old data which ware there before resetting the password..

Comment: Do you have a source or anything you could add to your post for a little extra validation?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot wipe after password change, you can't even download an app until you insert the new password. 
But why would you want to change the password in the first place if you would want it to be synced on the phone? I mean the thief then could still use it as normal if the password would sync automatically.

Comment: I don't *want* the new password to sync automatically. If I understand how the system works, when you change your Google password, you have to re-enter it on your device manually.

Comment: yes, I have specified that you can't do anything on your phone until you insert the new password

Comment: Then I don't understand your question: "why would you want to change the password in the first place if you would want it to be synced on the phone?"

Comment: You sayd that you would change your password so the phone won't sync and then you want to remotely wipe your data, witch is a sort of sync.

Comment: I never thought of wiping/erasing the phone as a sync, but I guess I learn something new every day...

Comment: wiping/erasing is not a sync, it is an operation that you want to do on a device, the command to do it is a sync, you synchronize the command to wipe the phone(in your case, but it can be any command from rebooting a phone to sent a tweet), so you synchronize the command and the phone executes it. So if you change the password, you cannot synchronize that change(if you could it can be dangerous), you manualy have to do it( that is to enter the NEW password on a device) so you can synchronize commands again. So it is easy to see why you could not wipe your phone after changing the password.

Answer (score 0):

If someone find your mobile and try to restore mobile. He need to enter your new google password. He can not bypass FRP lock without new password.

You can factory reset mobile. Use mobile or computer which you have used. You need to enter your password again.

Two factor verification use your email and mobile.

Answer (score -1):

Some phones may be bypassed with no problem - you just need to launch settings from a USB-OTG cable/drive, do the factory reset in the Backup settings and clean up all data related to Google accounts. After that you should do the reset again and FRP will be reset. So you will have an opportunity to use your phone like a new one. Read more here http://www.flexihub.com/remote-android-factory-reset.html